# Custom styling a list to reduce the space after a line

Tags: html, css, list, padding

I have the following [page](http://www.expandintheusa.com/register-now/) on a WordPress site that is generated by the code at the bottom of this post. Within the code, I have a set of nested lists that are highlighted in this [screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/04b3nr989e) in red. I would like to know the CSS I need to use to remove the line breaks marked in the screenshot by the blue arrows. If you look at the mess I have created in the HTML below, you will see that I have managed to do it elsewhere  using `style="margin: 0em !important; padding: 0em !important; -webkit-margin-after: 0em !important;"` but that has not worked on the list.

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="p1" style="text-align: center;">Register now!</h2>
<p class="p1"><strong>Register by December 31, 2014 and take advantage of our early bird offer and save!
</strong></p>
<p class="p1" style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">Registration includes two breakfasts, two
lunches, two end-of-day receptions, and free parking.</span>
</strong></p>
<p style="margin: 0em !important; padding: 0em !important; -webkit-margin-after: 0em !important;"><strong>Special offer for small and medium size enterprises and private equity firms:</strong></p>
<p style="font-size: 16px; -webkit-margin-before: 0em !important;">We are offering special, reduced registration rates for senior executives of qualifying small and medium size enterprises (SMEs) and for those in private equity.*</p>
<p style="font-size: 16px;">Register and pay by December 31, 2014 and save $400 for the first attendee and over $1,000 for three attendees from the same qualifying SME or private equity firm, by taking advantage of the following early bird rates:</p>
<p style="font-size: 16px; -webkit-margin-after: 0em !important;"><strong>One or more attendees from the same qualifying SME or private equity firm:</strong>
[table id=1 /]</p>
<p class="p1" style="font-size: 16px;">*To qualify for the special rate, you must be:</p>

<ul style="font-size: 16px;">
    <li>an owner, CEO, CFO, head of sales and marketing, or other senior executive at a business that:
        <ul>
            <li>Has fewer than 500 employees;</li>
            <li>Is headquartered in Canada; and</li>
            <li>Is not:
                <ul>
                    <li>in the business of offering legal, accounting, financial, consulting, brokerage, marketing, information technology, recruitment, logistics or other services to Canadian companies, related to trade and investment with the United States; or</li>
                    <li>a government entity</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<p style="font-size: 16px;">or:</p>

<ul style="font-size: 16px;">
    <li>a partner, managing director, vice president, or principal at a private equity firm, or a qualified investor.</li>
</ul>
<p style="margin: 0em !important; padding: 0em !important; -webkit-margin-after: 0em !important;"><strong>All other attendees can save $400, too, by registering now!
</strong></p>
[table id=2 /]
<p style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Cancellation Policies:</span> Should you be unable to attend this event, we require notice in writing on or before March 2, 2015 at 5:00pm, ET. Cancellations made after this date will not be eligible for a refund. All cancellations are subject to an administration fee equal to 50% of the invoiced purchase price.</p>
<p style="font-size: 14px;">Your registration may also be transferred to another individual at the same company at no charge. Should you wish to transfer your registration to another person, please inform us by <a href="mailto:customersupport@bivioevents.com">email</a>, a minimum of 24 hours prior to the event. Please be sure to include the following details: Name and Title of Attendee taking your spot, Company, Company Address, Direct Phone Number, Email Address, Name on Badge, and Company Name on Badge. In lieu of cancellation or transfer to another person at the same company, you may request a full credit for the amount paid to be applied to a future event, produced by Bivio Events Inc.</p>
<p style="font-size: 14px;">If for any reason whatsoever the conference is cancelled, the liability of Bivio Events Inc. shall be limited to reimbursement of the conference fees. Producer reserves the right, with reasonable notice, to make reasonable changes to program dates and venues and assumes no liability for the changes.</p>
<p style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Use of electronic recording devices: </b>Please note that the use of any electronic recording device of any kind is strictly prohibited during sessions.</p>
```

Comment: is there another css for ul li in your site?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look, I'm seeing your CSS file with the Chrome inspector:

```
media="all"
menu, ol, ul {
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

and...

```
media="all"
dl, menu, ol, ul {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Edit it! Replace 1em value for your custom value (in ems, pixels, whatever...), and do the same for the left padding.

Don't use inline styling, it's not good. Try to avoid it and always try to use external CSS to make stuff more maintainable.

Kind regards.

Comment: You don't want to remove padding.

Comment: Well man, just in case, I included it. Margin and padding are the spacings you are handling on those lists. What's with you man...

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that it was far easier than I thought. I just needed to set 
`ul{ margin:0;}`. All of the answers that suggest setting padding to zero don't seem to understand how lists work.

Comment: This is what I put on my answer. And I can't believe you are saying this if you are the one that doesn't seem to understand basics in the first place. This question should be spam.

Comment: I love that you said that you put that answer in your answer when your answer, which is immediately above mine, also includes setting padding to zero. Do you not realize that setting padding to zero breaks the entire functionality of the list?